Python integration for space and other metric consumption using Netdata
I am working on a python script which should be able to send the messages to google chat space via webhooks. I do not want alot of data. In my case, I have multiple hosts connected to a central server and I want to send the following metrics on the chats:

Space Usage
Swap Space Usage
RAM Usage

With the hostname/IP but I am not able to get it using the REST API of the netdata. I may be missing something as I just started using netdata. Any help/resouce in this regar will be appreciated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
